# XBAP Just Flashes and Won't Run with IE 11 on Windows 10 For Some User

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, xbap, windows-10-desktop

The XBAP is full-trust and it is signed correctly and it runs fine on most of the users. However, I have a user that is running Windows 10 and IE 11 and IE just flashes and the XBAP won't run. You can see the downloaded files window and the full IE window flashing on the screen. Only way to stop it is to end task it or reboot the computer. 
  I have added our site to the Trusted Sites. They are running McAfee for a virus scanner and I turned the real time scanner off and still got the same results.
Time zone, date and time are correct.
 
We have checked the file association of .XBAP with the Window Presentation Host. (Go to Control Panel -> Default Programs -> Associate a file type or protocol with a program.) The exe associated with the extension is C:\Windows\SysWOW64\PresentationHost.exe. 
Resetting IE did not work either.
Does anyone know what causes this? It looks like it wants to just download a file and seems like it doesn't know what to do with it.